# Prevent SVN from inserting "mine" and "theirs" blocks into conflicted code?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I prevent SVN from inserting "mine" and "theirs" blocks into my code files when I SVN update code that gets marked as conflicted?

When I make changes to a code file that has changed on the server since I last updated, SVN seems to manually insert "mine"/"theirs" blocks directly into my code when I update, making the code file undiffable in a merge tool. I would prefer if SVN did not modify my working copy on-disk (before I diff) so I can perform all of the diffing in my merge tool and then submit a merged file.

Edit: To be clear, I know about the two files that are generated: "foo.cs.mine", "foo.cs.r12". I could manually choose to diff those by selecting those two files in a merge tool and then writing out the result over "foo.cs", but that's a bunch of extra steps for something that's normally a "right-click -> diff" process normally. I'm looking into writing a bash script that does this for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion puts those *mine* and *theirs* blocks in your code for a reason. It wants you to handle that merge conflict. If Subversion simply ignored conflicts and just used your code, you could end up committing your code back into the repo, and remove the other developer's work.

I am not sure how TortoiseSVN works, but I know the command line will tell you about a merge conflict as it happens, then give you a choice of what you want to do: Take *their* code?, Take *your* code?, Accept *their* code for conflict?, Accept *your* code for conflicts?, Postpose resolution, and finally, launch [a third party merge tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.merge) for the merge.

90% of the time, I handle merge conflicts by hand -- looking at the *mine* and *their* blocks and figuring out what to do. Sometimes, I will launch into VimDiff to do the merge.

TortoiseSVN should give you similar options, and you can integrate [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/index.html) into TortoiseSVN to do these merges. You can probably integrate other third party merge tools into Subversion too. I've seen people setup Vimdiff and Gmacs to automatically start a merge when there are merge conflicts in the file.

One thing I do wish Subversion would have is a `--dry-run` option on an `svn update`. You have that with the standard merge that will help identify merge issues before you do a merge. It'd be nice if `svn update` had the same ability.

Comment: I guess there's no way around it. Thanks for the informative response!

Comment: svn update --dryrun does not exist, but 'svn st -u' shows you what has changed in the repository and will get updated.